# Cannot get this while function in C to work

Tags: c, while-loop

The while loop below is supposed to take user input five numbers from 1 to 10 and print them back.

What am I doing wrong?

**My Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[5];
int main()
{
  int ctr= 0,
  nbr = 0;
  printf("Enter 5 numbers from 1-10\n");

  while(ctr<5)
  {
    while(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10)
    {
      printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
      scanf("%d",&nbr);
    }

    array[ctr]= nbr;
    ctr++;
  }
  for (ctr=0;ctr<5;ctr++)
    printf("Value %d is %d\n",ctr+1,array[ctr]);

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: What is the problem you have? Can you please elaborate on that? Doesn't it build? Does it crash when you run the program? Give unexpected results? Please take some time to  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @KamiKaze This had nothing do with his problem.

Comment: @SurajJain yep, was just skimming through it and as he didn't specify the problem, I assumed this might help, but I after some thought I guess it only applies to `%c`

Comment: @KamiKaze Oh, it's ok :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider This Loop Of Your Program :

```
while(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10)
  {
   printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
   scanf("%d",&nbr);
  }
```

Here This loop will work for the first time because you have defined `nbr = 0`, so it satisfies the loop condition and goes inside it, then until you take a number between `1` and `10` it continues running, once you take a number that is between `1` and `10`, you leave the loop, but now because `nbr` is now between `1` and `10`, you will not go inside loop again.

This loop will therefore execute only once so that is why you are not able to take input of all `5` numbers.

If you after storing `nbr` in array, assign `nbr = 0` it now will again go into loop and your code will work fine.

**Correct Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[5];

int main(){

  int ctr= 0,
  nbr = 0;
  printf("Enter five numbers from 1-10\n");

  while(ctr<5){

    while(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10)//First time it enter the loop because nbr = 0
                              //But after that nbr is between 1 and 10
                              //So it does not enter again and you can not input more number.
    {
      printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
      scanf("%d",&nbr);
    }

    array[ctr]= nbr;
    nbr = 0;         //So That Loop Run Again
    ctr++;
  }
  for (ctr=0;ctr<5;ctr++)                 
    printf("Value %d is %d\n",ctr+1,array[ctr]);

  return(0);
}
```

Also There Are Other Ways that you can approach this problem, you can use `do-while` loop which executes the first time all the time and then check the condition.

**Another Method Using do-while loop**

```
    do
      {
        printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
        scanf("%d",&nbr);
      } while (nbr < 1 || nbr > 10);
```

Now here first you enter the number and it is stored in `nbr`, if it is between `1` and `10` you exit the loop and it gets stored in the array and now you again run the outer loop and again you encounter do while, it always execute the first time and then check the condition so you do not have to reinitialise `nbr = 0` every time.

**Tip**
Always Describe your problem more clearly and tell what you expected it to do and what it is doing so that other can understand it better and give you better and fast solutions.

Comment: why do i have to set nbr = 0; when that was done before the first while loop?

Comment: Because it will go inside loop only if it satisfies the condition `(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10)` , now first you have initialised nbr so this condition holds and we go inside loop and then it continues to run till nbr is between 1 - 10 and  after that we exit the loop and nbr is stored in array , now for another number you would again go to loop but this time because nbr is between 1- 10 , you wont enter the loop and will never be able to input any other number , see my answer again and ask if you still have doubt. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: @RhodosCoder See Above :)

Comment: @RhodosCoder Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10)
{
  printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
  scanf("%d",&nbr);
}

array[ctr]= nbr;
ctr++;

// Add this line after `ctr++`
nbr = 0; // <======
```

You have to reset `nbr` in order to reenter the *while* loop.

( Because after the first correct number `nbr` is entered, the while condition is always false. )

Answer (score 0):

`while(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10)` only works once, the first time when `nbr` is 0.

After that, `nbr` is valid, so you don't enter the loop again and your array is filled with the name number. You have to declare and initialize `int nbr = 0;` within the loop (you don't need outside the loop anyway).

```
 while(ctr<5)
  {
    int nbr = 0;
```

or use `do/while` instead of a condition that requires you to invalidate the value first:

```
do
{
  printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
  scanf("%d",&nbr);
} while(nbr < 1 || nbr > 10);
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the variable names are so explicit! How could have missed that :)

Comment: Jean, his loops are OK. He only forgot to reset `nbr`. I disagree with your updated loop; it is less clear.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Is  mine answer correct ?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You'll agree that with a do/while it's better (as Joachim nicely commented). I really don't like the need to invalidate a condition to be able to enter once in the while loop. It's error prone (as we saw here :). I used while/break out of bad python habit.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the , to a ; after initializing the variable ctr or have it written as show below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
      int array[5];
      int ctr= 0, nbr = 0;
      printf("Enter 5 numbers from 1-10\n");

      while(ctr<5)
      {
          //greater than zero includes 1, less than 11 includes 10
          while(nbr > 0 || nbr < 11)
          {
               printf("\nEnter number %d of 5:  ",ctr+1);
               scanf("%d",&nbr);
           }

           array[ctr]= nbr;
           ctr++;
         }
    for (ctr=0;ctr<5;ctr++)
    {
        printf("Value %d is %d\n",ctr+1,array[ctr]);
    }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please See his code again it is same as your code , his code is just hard to  understand , he did int ctr = 0, and on next line nbr = 0; so it is same as yours.